# How to communicate containers in ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In Kubernetes cluster pods can easily communicate using its dns names or ip. Like this how can I know dns name of any container and communicate between two containers between 2 different EC2 machines.

Answer (score 2):

In Kubernetes, cluster pods use kube-dns to connect between them.

So in ECS, it has its [service discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/) itself. Or if you want to connect tasks in the same cluster, you can use their names to connect.

An example is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html)

Comment: I tried this example but it is not working when containers are running in different ec2 instance. Any idea why it causing problem?

Comment: What is the error? Timeout or access denied?

Comment: Timeout error I guess it means not reachable.

Comment: Can you try do an nslookup and check if your service can see others?

Comment: nslookup also not working

Comment: So your container can't see other services. Maybe issue with service discovery

Comment: Still not figure out what causing the issue. Do we need to setup any networking setup between ec2 instances to make service reachable. Because when 2 service run on one ec2 instance it works but fails when seperated by different ec2 instance.

Comment: If nslookup is not working, maybe the error come from Subnet Configuration. Can you check if your subnet has DNS enabled?

Answer (score 0):

For other people that come here, if your containers are **in the same cluster** but **in different services** a good choice can be [aws Ecs Service Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-connect.html)
Try to make your implementation by **aws cli** or by **cloudformation**. At least until today(20.03.2023) I found the info for implementation via the aws console confusing.
So if you decide by console pay attention to the task definition json and check the following fields, in your Task Definition, have been properly configured:

```
 "portMappings": [
            {
                "name": "port_name",
                "containerPort": port_numb,
                "hostPort": 9000,
                "protocol": "tcp",
                "appProtocol": "http"
            }
```

And pay attention to the **network mode** documentation explaining that the default value is **bridge** but you need to specify:

```
   ......
  "networkMode": "bridge",
   ......
```

The rest of explanation is quite well explained and keep in mind with  network mode **bridge** you can control and to see containers at docker level but with is **awsvpc** you need to create security groups for containers and save DNS records pointed on AWS Cloud Map and I think this can be another scenario